# Is it relevant enough to create a direct .php file as an AJAX target in Magento (instead of standard router path)

Tags: ajax, performance, magento

I will explain a bit of background here. The AJAX I'm going to use must work very fast, implementing some logic on the backend and returning JSON as response.

I'm not new in Magento development, but I've struggled to create a *cheap* request using standard Magento request flow. Using profiler I've discovered, that only the **routing** work (including `match`, `preDispatch`, `rewrite` and more light-weighted, but numerous small routing-related functions)  takes almost a second.

Have no doubts, I'm loading all the necessary data to bootstrap application, my script looks very much like scripts in the `shell` directory.

So using my own *.php* file instead of Magento router I'm already saving almost a second per request - without even touching the logic. My benchmarking may be not very accurate, but the point is - I'm definitely saving some time, when time is very essential for me.

So the questions are: **is this 1 sec worth neglecting of Magento architecture**? Has anyone implemented something similar? And where is the best place to put such file into, considering Magento Module approach?

I'll be glad, if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You've got the intelligence and knowledge to profile your code.  You have the intelligence and knowledge the make this decision yourself.  Stop second guessing yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Alan, you're right, shouldn't have asked that, the decision will still be only mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following the script approach. (in case anyone wonder)

Answer (score 1):

Do not neglect the magento architecture.

The way to do this is have a module with a controller action, that would be called by the ajax call. 
In the config file add a frontend router which ever you feel is right and you would call that frontend address when making the ajax call

For example this below would be called by the front end call 'ajaxcontent':

```
<frontend>
            <routers>
                <ajaxmodule>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Companyname_Ajaxcontent</module>
                        <frontName>ajaxcontent</frontName>
                    </args>
                </gajaxmodule>
            </routers>
        </frontend>
```

This is some basic guidance feel free to post back if u get stuck on this..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is actually the router approach I was talking about in my question.